# Unable to build Nginx (unrecognized option)

Tags: nginx, build, configure

I am having some issues when configuring nginx, I have the following:

```
./configure \
--user=www-data \
--group=www-data \
--prefix=/etc/nginx \
--sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx \
--conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
--pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid \
--lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock \
--error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log \
--http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log \
--with-debug \
--with-http_gzip_static_module \
--with-http_stub_status_module \
--with-http_ssl_module \
--with-pcre \
--with-file-aio \
--with-http_realip_module \
--with-http_v2_module \
--with-pcre-jit \
--with-ipv6 \
--add-module=/root/modsecurity \
--add-module=/root/ngx_pagespeed-1.12.34.2-beta ${PS_NGX_EXTRA_FLAGS} \
--add-module=/root/headers-more-nginx
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
configure: error: unrecognized option: `--user=www-data'
```

If I try removing that option then the next option will give the exact same.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Strangely I managed to fix it by removing the following:
     --add-module=/root/modsecurity \